# Mouse drag to a target with InputSimulator

Tags: c#, wpf, coded-ui-tests

I need to drag a WPF element and drop in on another WPF target element. I have been using InputSimulator for all my keyboard interaction in my test code. But didn't find anything about mouse dragging with InputSimulator. Any insight on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the native coded ui methods from Mouse Class. Something like,

**Edit Per OP Request:**

```
// Determine drop coordinates dynamically       
Point dropDestinationPoint = controlYouWanttoDropOn.GetClickablePoint();
// Add some buffer to avoid possible clicking over the edges - Optional
dropDestinationPoint.X += 5; 
dropDestinationPoint.Y += 5;    
Mouse.StartDragging(controlYouWantToDrag);
Mouse.StopDragging(controlYouWanttoDropOn, dropDestinationPoint);
```

You can also try and get points thru BoundingRectangle property and play with it.

Comment: I have thought about it before, but I have a question here. the dropDestinationPoint.X - how do you get this co-ordinate? If say the resolution of the screen changes, wont the script fail?

Comment: It would, you can get the points dynamically. Updated the answer!!

Comment: I am trying to figure out. GetClickable() method is not present for any WPF  element. But have got the property Rectagle() which gives 4 co-ordinates of the destination element and let you know.

Comment: Yuhuuu...it works absolutely great!! Let me post final code:

Comment: System.Drawing.Rectangle dropDestination = wpfElement.GetScreenRectangle();
System.Drawing.Point dest = new System.Drawing.Point(dropDestination.X + 5, dropDestination.Y + 5);
            Mouse.StartDragging();
            Mouse.StopDragging(dest);